# Why I have a lot of dependecies in requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I tried to deploy flask app in heroku and I got problem with the requirements.txt file. I have more than 100 modules. Do i need 100 modules for to host? What can I do?

this is the error i get:

-----> Python app detected

-----> Installing python-3.6.11

-----> Installing pip 20.0.2, setuptools 39.0.1 and wheel 0.34.2

-----> Installing SQLite3

-----> Installing requirements with pip

```
   Collecting alabaster==0.7.8

     Downloading alabaster-0.7.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)

   Collecting alembic==1.4.2

     Downloading alembic-1.4.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)

     Installing build dependencies: started

     Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'

     Getting requirements to build wheel: started

     Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'

       Preparing wheel metadata: started

       Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'

   Collecting appdirs==1.4.4

     Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)

   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_1d344ed6_/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: none)

   ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_1d344ed6_/requirements.txt (line 4))
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

!     Push failed

Comment: What was the error you got when trying to deploy the flask app? Also if dependencies are in `requirements.txt`, then more likely than not they are ***requirements*** . The issue is probably that it is unable to find/retrieve a package, some dependencies need to be updated, or some requirements conflict with each other.

Comment: You created that file, you should know what you need. And without any details, how could we possibly help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have made your requirements.txt using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
then it will contain all the module you have installed your whole life.

If you are running a flask application, then you only need to add `flask` to your requirements.txt. if you are using any other libraries as well, then you can also include it in your requirements.txt.

Also, heroku recommends using `gunicorn` and so you only need to include  `flask` and `gunicorn` in your requirements.txt or others which you require and can be installed using `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error message you got?

If you generated the `requirements.txt` using the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and it contains dependencies which you haven't used, then maybe you're not in a virtual environment which contains just the packages for this project.